# PostgreSQL pgbouncer configuration - pgbouncer user is currently not available

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I have already succeded installed pgbouncer on postgresql 10 , and it created me a pgbouncer user nad from there i run pgbouncer pgbouncer.ini to start the pooling. but now when I try to install pgbouncer on another machine I can't seem to access the pgbouncer user anymore.
I try: su - pgbouncer and I get this error: This account is currently not available.

I have configured the pgbouncer.ini and userlist.txt files but nothing helps....

Comment: What is the operating system? How exactly did you install the software?

Comment: CentOS 8 , yum install pgbouncer

Comment: What do you get for `id pgbouncer` on the shell?

Comment: uid=969(pgbouncer) gid=966(pgbouncer) groups=966(pgbouncer)

Comment: Great, then everything is fine. Start it with `systemctl start pgbouncer`.

Comment: Oh ok!!! it works! but do you know why on the other machine i can log to the pgbouncer user and I run pgbouncer pgbouncer.ini to start the pooling?

Comment: The operating system or the user are configured differently.